# What could make the "System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll" unregister from my system

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference

I have an C# application that uses some custom lets say some.dll and the dll references the "System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll". The application was working fine until I rebuilt the some.dll and replaced it with the original dll in my system.

Now when I try to start the application it is giving the error "Exception ::Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.resources, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=en-NZ, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

The error persists even if I replace the new dll with original one.

I suspect that the System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll has been unregistered. Can anybody explain what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the application is trying to read all the .dlls placed in a folder and when I replaced the existing some.dll, I renamed it as some.dll.back(or some.back.dll, I don't exactly remeber) and kept it in the same folder. The application considered the some.back.dll and tried to load it and got this error. I deleted the some.dll before replacing my own version of the some.dll and it didn't show any error, confirmed that it was the root cause.